How to get client IP from inside a custom realm?
I have a java web app on tomcat which implements user authentication with j_security_check.
I am trying to log into the db the failed login attempts. I tried several methods (listeners,valve,filter) with no success and I am trying with a custom realm which works and seems like a pretty and effortless solution BUT my problem is that i want to also log the client's IP and as far as I know i don't have access to the request object inside the realm so i can't get the IP. I searched so much but with no success.
My code is
public class CustomLoginRealm extends DataSourceRealm {


    @Override
    public Principal authenticate(String username, String credentials) {
        System.out.println("AUTHENTICATE in CustomLoginRealm");
        System.out.println("Thread in Realm: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        Principal principal = super.authenticate(username, credentials);

        if (principal == null) {
            logFailedLoginAttempt(username);
        }

        return principal;
    }

    private void logFailedLoginAttempt(String username) {

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUsername, dbPassword)) {
            String details = "Username/password mismatch";
            Date date = new Date();

            String query = "INSERT INTO U_LOGIN_FAILED_ATTEMPTS (TIMESTAMP, USERNAME, DETAILS) "
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

            try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
                ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
                ps.setString(2, username);
                ps.setString(3, details);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


Your question is tagged with MongoDB Realm, the NoSQL database. Can you update the question as to how the question relates to that tag? Are you using MongoDB Authentication?

you can get the user-id and ip of the client from the tomcat access log. and correlate time stamp with the authentication log. You can also resolve ip to DNS name.

@Jay I don't know how it is related to Mongo DB realm, the tag I entered says just "realm". For the record no, I'm using oracle SQL db

You can hover over a tag with your mouse cursor and it will reveal details about the tag. Thanks for updating the tags.
